# Getting value of a "object HTMLInputElement" and function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have checkboxes on a page and I get the checked ones then I loop through them;

```
var checkeds = $('#accTypes input:checked');
    var values = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < checkeds.length; i++) {
        console.log(checkeds[i]);
        var cval = checkeds[i].val();
        values = values + "," + cval;
    }
```

I recognized that the row below causes error.

```
checkeds[i].val()
```

When I print the checkeds[i] variable in chrome console, I see;

```
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"accom-check" id=​"checkboxP12" value=​"12">​
```

I wanted to get the value of checkeds[i] variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A jQuery collection is an array-like object containing native DOM nodes.

When you access it as `checkeds[1]` you get the native DOM node, not the jQuery version, so it doesn't have a `val()` method.

Either use the native value

```
var cval = checkeds[i].value;
```

or use `eq()` to get the jQuery object

```
var cval = checkeds.eq(i).val();
```

As a sidenote, you could do the same thing with a map

```
var values = $('#accTypes input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```